# Carrying over order_id with Ajax to php and inserting to database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am attempting to write AJAX for the first time and I am having some difficulties getting the order_id figure to send over to my php file and then send to my db. As of now nothing is sending.

What I am trying to do is, I have a file that I am going to be using to mark the status of shipments. In each row(shipment record) I have a button and inside of the button is the text "Mark Shipped". So when I ship the item, I want to press the button and that button be labelled 'Shipped'. I then want the status of `Shipped` to be there indefinitely. But I would like the option to turn it back to `Marked Shipped`, if it was ever clicked accidentally.

I figured out one of the ways I could do this is with Ajax and having php send the status of the record to my db.

The part I can't figure out is how to get the current shipping record's order_id to send over to my php file. I get the following error when I click the button..

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: order_id is not defined
```

Am I doing this right? Before I added the Ajax, I just had the part in the JS code under //Getting shipping status button to change....

and it at least changed the button when pressed. Now nothing works.

How can I get the `order_id` figure to send over and this to function right?

I'm obtaining the `order_id` through a php `while loop` like this:

```
<td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['order_id']; ?> </td>
```

This my Ajax code

```
<script>
$("button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var el = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "shippingStatusSend.php",
        data: {
            action: "Shipped",
            order: order_id
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text"
    }).fail(function(e, t, m) {
        console.log(e, t, m);
    }).done(function(r) {
        //Getting Shipping Status button to chance from 'mark as shipped' to 'shipped'
        el.text() == el.data("text-swap") ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
    });
});
</script>
```

My php file

```
<?php
//connection to db
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bfb"); 

//Check for errors  
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf ("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
    $order_id = trim($_POST['order_id'] );
    $status = trim($_POST['action'] );

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO shippingStatus (order_id, status, date_Shipped) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())")) {

/* bind parameters for markers */
            $stmt->bind_param('is', $order_id, $status);

            /* execute query */
            $stmt->execute();


        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've to get the `order_id` from the HTML(**Assuming only one .tdproduct is available on page**).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "shippingStatusSend.php",
    data: {
        action: "Shipped",
        order_id: $.trim($('.tdproduct').text())
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text"
}).fail(function(e, t, m) {
```

Comment: No, .tdproduct is my css element to style the table rows.

Comment: @Paul Did You try it?

Comment: it mostly works. The order_id is not fully carried over though. It shows up as a zero.

Comment: Then how can I get this to reverse back to "Marked to Shipped" if I had to with some kind of alert pop up before I goes back?

Comment: @Paul You can use `done` callback param to get data from server

Comment: Ok, the order_id transfers over, but the "Shipped", doesn't stay in the actual button upon reload. How can I get this to stay once changed?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on this

in your html edit the button use data attribute

```
<button data-order_id="<?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>">mark as shipped</button>
```

**in javascript**

```
<script>
$("button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var el = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "shippingStatusSend.php",
        data: {
            action: "Shipped",
            order: el.data('order_id')
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text"
    }).fail(function(e, t, m) {
        console.log(e, t, m);
    }).done(function(r) {
        //Getting Shipping Status button to chance from 'mark as shipped' to 'shipped'
        el.text() == el.data("text-swap") ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
    });
});
</script>
```